# Redirecting to a URL that is sent through an API Response

Tags: php, api

I'm new in programming and API and I want to know how can I redirect to the URL sent by an API Response like below, please take note that the merchantURL changes everytime a customer submit new transaction.

```
decision = ACCEPT
reasonCode = 100
requestID = 5199043764236716204011
requestToken = AhjnrwSTGdc55dvfMd/rmBles0iRokq1GiOZKW+XDR/x6Q27g++QyaSZbpAcCSAkxnXOeXb3zHf6wAAAAQqe
apSaleReply->reasonCode = 100
apSaleReply->merchantURL = https://www.sofort.com/payment/go/3e54e5e50b5114f5c11ef40b2d45dbb7a4d808b3
```

This is how I requested the merchantURL:

```
printf( "apSaleReply->merchantURL = " . $reply->apSaleReply->merchantURL . "<br>");
```

and I have an IF statement that if the reason code is equal to 100 then it will redirect to the URL:

```
if ($reply->reasonCode == 100){
?>    
    <script>
    window.location.href = "";
    </script>
<?php

}
```

This is already working if I input any URL, I'm only stuck on how to get the value of the merchantURL since it is always changing and specify it in the window.location.href.

Hope you can help me out! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try this `window.location.href = "<?php echo $reply->apSaleReply->merchantUR; ?>";`

Comment: Why not use a header instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use php header

header("Location: " . $reply->apSaleReply->merchantUR );

> Or you can alter your existing code as below to get this work

```
if ($reply->reasonCode == 100){
    ?>    
    <script>
    window.location.href = "<?php echo $reply->apSaleReply->merchantUR; ?>";
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Ok all the best dude. You can mark my answer as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
window.location.href = "<?= $reply->apSaleReply->merchantURL ?>";
```

(I assume your template and back-end code is in the same file, otherwise use a session data. Let me know if it's the case.)

Comment: Yup it's in the same file, but it didn't work/redirect me. What's the "=" for?

Comment: <?= VARNAME ?> is the short of <?php echo VARNAME ?>...I see a typo in my answer, I fixed it, you can try again.